# Issue with "requests" import in Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Using OS X I've installed Python 2.7 and the `requests` module through terminal. If I run `pip list` I can see that `requests (2.10.0)` is on the list. However, When I open my script and write `import requests` in a IDE I get the error: `No module named requests`. I've tried a lot of solutions, but none of them work.

Comment: Which IDE? Is it configured to use the same interpreter that you've installed `requests` in? What solutions have you tried, and what exactly happened when you tried them?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm CE.  I'm not sure about the second part, I'll check...

Comment: It is definitely worthwhile to say what you've tried, especially if you've tried a lot of them. Will save people answering loads of effort suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: Yes, that worked... Thank you so much. I've configured interpreter in PyCharm Preferences and now works fine. :)

Comment: I've tried different installations of python versions and modules, and terminal commands to change user permissions but no success.

Comment: *"now works fine. :)"* or *"no success"*? If you still have a problem, [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Now works fine. :)